# Why is it «du hasard» instead of «au hasard» in this context?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

In the song «La chute est lente» one line goes «Au debut, c'était du hasard/Quelques fois tu rentres un peu tard». Why does the singer use «du» instead of «au hasard», which is what I've been taught to say when I want to say something happened by chance or randomly, does «du hasard» not translate to "by chance"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this sentence *hasard* has its primary meaning of "chance". It means **by chance**, **by accident**, **haphazardly**.

- *On ne s'était pas donné rendez-vous. Je l'ai rencontré par hasard an allant faire les courses*.
  → We hadn't planned a meeting. I met him by chance on my way to the shops.
- *« C'est souvent du hasard que nait l'opinion. »* (a famous quote from Jean de la Fontaine)
  → It is often by chance that opinion is born<sup>1</sup>.

*Au hasard* is a set phrase that  means **at random**/**randomly**.

- *Si tu ne sais pas lequel choisir prends en un au hasard*.
  → If you don't know which one to choose take one at random.

That's how I understand those lyrics:
" At first it was by chance (by accident/haphazardly), sometimes you come home a little late..."

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My literal translation. Walter Thornbury's translation in his translation of the *Fables* in verse: "Opinion is the child of Chance".</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*Hasard* is uncountable: *du hasard* = *"de le" hasard* = some *hasard*.

I'd translate it "At first, **it was random**", i.e. it was happening unpredictably.

The underlying meaning is that the late arrivals were initially rare but as time went on, they became more and more common and therefore predictable.

*C'était au hasard* wouldn't have work well because there was no actual randomness in what happened, it was just perceived as such by the person speaking.